# I want to copy the content of immediate previous sheet to new sheet within same work book

Tags: vba, excel

My work book have total of 7 sheets four of which are hidden. I want to

1. Create A new Sheet using VBA
2. copy all contents of Last sheet to above created new sheet

i tried  using below code

```
sheet_name_to_create = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")

For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.count)
If LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) = LCase(sheet_name_to_create) Then
MsgBox " This Sheet already exists"
Exit Sub
End If
Next
ActiveSheets.copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = sheet_name_to_create
```

but this code create new copies of all existing sheets(all 7 sheet i have in workbook).

Please suggest the best possible soln.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

Macro will ask you for name for new sheet and then copy last sheet.

```
Sub AddNewSheet()
sheet_name_to_create = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")
For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)
    If LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) = LCase(sheet_name_to_create) Then
    MsgBox " This Sheet already exists"
    Exit Sub
    End If
Next
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = sheet_name_to_create
End Sub
```

Comment: @cundy I have one more question the excel sheet I am copying have formulas which derive data from previous sheets. can these formula refrences get updated automatically somehow?

Comment: You can change references in whole sheet simply using CTRL+H if i understood you correctly. If you want to add it to macro, use macro recorder and modify outcome for your needs.